# Add delay on mouseover with constructor

Tags: javascript

I've got a navigation built with JS using a class constructor. This is the code for the mouseover/mouseout functionality

```
export default class MeganavItem {
    constructor(element, meganav) {
        this.element = element;
        this.meganav = meganav;

        this.content = element.querySelector(selectors.content);

        this.menus = Array
            .from(element.querySelectorAll(selectors.menus))
            .map(menu => new MeganavMenu(menu, this));

        this.attachEvents();
    }

    attachEvents() {
        this.element.addEventListener('mouseover', e => this.openContent(e));
        this.element.addEventListener('mouseout', e => this.closeContent(e));
    }

    openContent() {
        this.content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    }

    closeContent() {
        this.content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
    }
}
```

However, I need to delay the mouseover by 100ms and not sure how to do this within the attachEvents function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) for the delay:

```js
export default class MeganavItem {
    constructor(element, meganav) {
        this.element = element;
        this.meganav = meganav;
        this.openning = false; // add a flag here to prevent multiple triggers.

        this.content = element.querySelector(selectors.content);

        this.menus = Array
            .from(element.querySelectorAll(selectors.menus))
            .map(menu => new MeganavMenu(menu, this));

        this.attachEvents();
    }

    attachEvents() {
        // Note: the mouseover listener is rewritten
        this.element.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
          if (!this.openning) {
            this.openning = true;
            window.setTimeout(() => {
              this.openContent(e);
              this.openning = false;
            }, 100);
          }
        });
        this.element.addEventListener('mouseout', e => this.closeContent(e));
    }

    openContent() {
        this.content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    }

    closeContent() {
        this.content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
    }
}
```